# Simple intent not showing up? [Still doesn't have an accepted answer]

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent, manifest

I am working with service intents right now, and have just made a simple project. I have added a log tag to a service intent whenever my app starts up. The issue is that after my app starts up, I don't get the log message in my logcat.

I added some toasts to be displayed on the screen before and after the calling of the service intent, and those both run fine perfectly, but the code in between doesn't even show itself.

**Its weird because the code around it runs fine!**

Here is my java file where I am calling the service intent:

[image: java]

Here is my intent service java file:

[image: Intent service]

Here is my log configuration:

[image: log filter]

here is the relevant portion of my manifest:

[image: Manifest]

Please explain to me why the logs don't show up. This is especially odd since I am not getting any errors, and the toasts are showing up. Thank you so much for all of your help, I really appreciate it.

**Any** feedback would be greatly appreciated, as I have been at this problem for over an hour now!

Comment: In the logcat filter, can you try to use `Package Name` instead of `Log Tag (regex)` and see if you can see the log message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you check if service is started?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService(android.content.Intent)

**Returns**
If the service is being started or is already running, the ComponentName of the actual service that was started is returned; else if the service does not exist null is returned.

Comment: How do I check if the service have started?

Comment: I don't think the service is even starting, because I put a Toast in the service itself as well, and that didn't even display on the screen. Please help.

Comment: You can use startService() and get return value to check if service is started first, and then we can think about next step.

Comment: What would be an appropriate way to get the return value? Thank you.

Comment: Have ComponentName class to get the return value from startService() and check if ComponentName is as your expectation.